# IE7 and 8 CSS menu background dropdown hover issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

Hoping someone can help with a fresh pair of eyes, have been banging my head against a brick wall trying to fix an issue in IE7-8 where dropdown menu items jump around when hovered over - some negative margin rules are being applied on hover (as well as an ugly block background) and I can't see why this is happening in IE7-8 and not in other browsers (even IE6 I have working correctly!). I've commented out my attempts at the bottom of the app.css stylesheet. Basically the dropdown menu is overriding some of the styles from Twitter bootstrap. which is included before the app.css applies custom styles.

Here is a [demo link][1] (only the dropout menu styling is the issue at the moment, i realise the top level items aren't very legible!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

background on hover is because of this code which is coming from bootstrap.css line no 6.filter property is use to apply gradient in ie.in line no 106 app.css all property is override but not filter so in ie there is blue background.

```
.dropdown-menu li > a:hover, .dropdown-menu li > a:focus, .dropdown-submenu:hover > a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #08C;
    background-color: #0081C2;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#08C,#0077B3);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,from(#08C),to(#0077B3));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#08C,#0077B3);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#08C,#0077B3);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#08C,#0077B3);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff0088cc',endColorstr='#ff0077b3',GradientType=0);
    }
```

Comment: thanks, that sorts the background issue - will post hover margin issue separately as have more information on that one